# How to instantiate Fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to write a unit test for my Fragment class. 
Is it possible to instantiate "System Under Test" this way?

```
val sut = MyFragment()
```

I understand there are several methods for writing UI tests for testing fragments, but I want to instantiate my Fragment class where I can unit test methods within the fragment.

such as ,

```
@Test
fun testComponents() {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    val context = sut.requireContext()
    sut.checkPwdEditTextIsEmpty(text = "")
}
```

How can I do this in Kotlin??

Also, how can I write init() and tearDown() in Kotlin test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods like `requireContext()` and accessing the Views of a Fragment require the Fragment to be added to a FragmentManager. As per the [Test your app's fragments documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing), you can use `FragmentScenario` to write exactly those types of tests:

```
@Test
fun testComponents() {
    val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>()
    scenario.onFragment { sut ->
        val context = sut.requireContext()
        sut.checkPwdEditTextIsEmpty(text = "")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully with a minimum code. Thank you so much!